# How to import plotly.js into TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, plotly

I'm trying to import `plotly.js` into TypeScript. Plotly.js is installed using `npm`. In my TypeScript file I use

```
import 'plotly.js';
```

It's OK but I'm getting error on code like `Plotly.<member>`:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Plotly'
```

When I try

```
import Plotly = require('plotly.js');
```

I'm getting

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'plotly.js'.
```

Comment: You can use the [previous version if the current one has issues](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/42558).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ended up with:

```
declare function require(moduleName: string): any;
var Plotly = require('plotly.js/lib/index-basic.js');
```

(Referring to index-basic.js as I need just the basic functionality, use index.js for the full library.)

**EDIT (Feb 2018):**

The preferred way now is adding path into `tsconfig.json` file, like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
        "plotly.js": [
            "../node_modules/plotly.js/lib/core.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

and then import in `.ts` file like

```
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js';
```

Note: in the path I included only `core.js`, which contains `scatter` graphs, you can import other graphs as you need.

(I'm using it with Angular CLI - Angular 5.2 and Typesript 2.7.1)

Comment: I am doing  `var Plotly = require('plotly.js/dist/plotly.js')` which is also working fine. Do you know, how both are different?

Comment: @yugantarkumar I only include basic module (I needed only scatter graph). You inlcude the full library. Check this link https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md

Comment: I only searched for this issue because Plotly.js was not working on IE11. 
@yugantarkumar version worked for me on IE11 but some error related to `vertx` occured. The final solution for me was as @eXavier added (Feb 2018) but `"../node_modules/plotly.js/lib/index-basic.js"` (core.js wasn't enough to render basic charts).

Answer (score 27):

There is a Definitely Typed version available for plotly.js ([Github link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/plotly.js)). This allows you to use the plain Javascript version inside Typescript. Follow these steps to setup your environment:

```
npm install --save plotly.js
npm install --save-dev @types/plotly.js
```

Then in your code you can do the following (example taken from [Github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/plotly.js)):

```javascript
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js';

const data: Plotly.BarData[] = [
  {
    x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y: [20, 14, 23],
    type: 'bar'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('test', data);
```

Finally you need to convert the Typescript to javascript with `tsc` and prepare the code to be included in you webpage with `browserify`.

This also works now with ionic 2! Make sure you manually add the following packages:

```
npm install --save glslify
npm install --save mapbox-gl
```

Comment: plotly.js can also be used in ionic 2

Comment: I'm getting 404 errors using typed plotly: node_modules/plotly.js/src/traces/bar.js 404 (Not Found), node_modules/plotly.js/src/traces/box.js 404 (Not Found) and so on. Did you have this problem?

Comment: You could just write `import Plotly from 'plotly.js';` as the library has a line `export as namespace Plotly;`

Comment: what type do I use that contains everything needed for a chart? data, and layout and config etc in one type?

Answer (score 9):

#### Types for plotly.js basic & Co.

You can also use types together with the [partial npm bundles](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md#partial-bundles) like basic or cartesian, starting in `v1.39.0`. Example for plotly.js basic (contains `scatter`, `pie` and `bar`):

```
npm i plotly.js-basic-dist
npm i -D @types/plotly.js
```

Add the following in tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  // make aliases absolute imports relative to the project root
  "baseUrl": "./",                
  "paths": {
    "plotly.js-basic-dist": [
      "node_modules/@types/plotly.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Above `paths` config just maps your imported `plotly.js-basic-dist` package to those types defined in `@types/plotly.js`, so you can use them with `plotly.js-basic-dist`. More Infos:

- [baseUrl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url)
- [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)

Comment: Nice. When using Create React App, this needs some trickery using `"extends"` [to fix its build process](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8909#issuecomment-624681463): _The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file: compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)_. But that trickery works fine too.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Also make the changes @Arjan mentions.

Answer (score 8):

## TS support

```
npm install --save-dev @types/plotly.js`
```

or

```
yarn add --dev @types/plotly.js`
```

and

```
import { PlotData } from "plotly.js"; // or whatever you need
```

⚠️*Don't install @types in dependencies since they are used exclusively for development purposes.*

## Problem

Since you add types for **plotly.js**, you expect to import stuff from **plotly.js** instead of a specific module. This is all good until you want to use it with react i.e. **react-plotly + plotly.js** ☹️

I know you didn't mention React explicitly, but I figured you or anyone else with a similar issue might find this useful.

I am not sure about your bundling approaches, however, I'm using Webpack 4 and currently investigating a **react-plotly + plotly.js-basic-dist** combination.

Possible combinations are:

- [react-plotly + plotly.js-basic-dist](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md#plotlyjs-basic) – my choice. You can add more bundles if needed
- [react-plotly + CDN](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js#use-the-plotlyjs-cdn-hosted-by-fastly)
- [react-plotly + custom bundle](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js#modules)

More about [customising plotly bundles](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js#customizing-the-plotlyjs-bundle).

This brings the bundle size down significantly and the sun shines upon us once again.

BUT...

Since this approach will require a factory and custom dist, these, as of this writing, don't have types

```
import Plotly from "plotly.js-basic-dist";
import createPlotlyComponent from "react-plotly.js/factory";
const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);
```

## FIX

1. #### Create a @types folder

   [image]
2. #### Add typeRoots to tsconfig.json

   [image]

**N.B.** The following approach did fix the types for the above imports, but I still have a failing compilation, which I didn't manage to fix following the accepted answer:
[image]

Hope you have a better experience!

---

## UPDATE

I fixed the compiling issue. It was because react-plotly.js was being bundled in the 'dependencies`. For my case vendor deps are handled like this:

```js
/**
 * Given an array of files this will produce an object which contains the values for the vendor entry point
 */
function makeVendorEntry(config) {
    const packageJson = require('../package.json');
    const vendorDependencies = Object.keys(packageJson['dependencies']);

    const vendorModulesMinusExclusions = vendorDependencies.filter(vendorModule =>
        config.mainModules.indexOf(vendorModule) === -1 && config.modulesToExclude.indexOf(vendorModule) === -1);

    return vendorModulesMinusExclusions;
}

exports.makeVendorEntry = makeVendorEntry;
```

Instead I moved `react-plotly.js` to the devDependencies and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

If the npm library you are importing does not provide type declarations itself, you'll have to import them yourself. The preferred tool is [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings).

For plotly, it seems someone already made a declaration file. So once you have typings installed (`npm i -g typings`) you can search for the type declaration of plotly (`typings search plotly`). You'll see that there is a declaration file available on [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/). After you initialize typings for your project (`typings init`), you can install the declaration file (`typings i --global --save plotly.js`).

Notice the `--global`. This specific declaration file is a **global declaration file**. This means that you don't have to import any types, as the types are available everywhere in your project. Eg.

```
// app.ts
let myPlotlyConfig: PlotlyConfig
```

Comment: Generally, you're right with the typings. The ones for Plotly are just in a very early stadium, just 1 function actually so it is not usable yet. Anyway +1

Answer (score 1):

Install plotly.js using NPM:

```
npm install --save plotly.js
```

Then in component or service wherever you want to use import like:

```
import Plotly from 'plotly.js/lib/core';
Plotly.register([
 require('plotly.js/lib/heatmap'),
 require('plotly.js/lib/bar'),
 require('plotly.js/lib/pie') // can include as many plot types as you want
]);
```

Use plotly lib as below:

```
const data: Plotly.BarData[] = [
 {
   x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
   y: [20, 14, 23],
   type: 'bar'
 }
];

Plotly.newPlot('test', data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could not find a declaration file for module 'plotly.js/dist/plotly.js'. 'C:/Users/spriy28/TEST2/tst/node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

To remove the error use this.

Add `noImplicitAny: false` in tsconfig json file to remove the error.

Comment: Its really very helpful.